# How do I add icons to a menubar in uwp

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp, menubar

I am trying to make an uwp app, which has a menubar, although I would like to add icons to it(not to it's menuflyoutitems), like a mac os menubar has icons on the right-hand side. I am trying to achieve the same thing, but have found nothing. please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to make an uwp app, which has a menubar, although I would like to add icons to it(not to it's menuflyoutitems),

Sure, for this scenario, the better way is custom `MenuBarItem` style, and update the `ContentButton` content with icon but not default Title propety.

**For example**

```
<Style x:Key="ImageBarItem" TargetType="MenuBarItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBorderThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Title" Value="Item" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ExitDisplayModeOnAccessKeyInvoked" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuBarItem">

                <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="Transparent" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" Color="Transparent" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="Transparent" />
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Border
                        x:Name="Background"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />

                    <Button
                        x:Name="ContentButton"
                        Padding="12,0,12,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        IsTabStop="False">
                        <!--add icon-->
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add" />
                    </Button>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Background.Background" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            <Setter Target="Background.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Background.Background" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            <Setter Target="Background.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Background.Background" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                            <Setter Target="Background.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource MenuBarItemBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>

                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage**

```
 <MenuBar VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <MenuBarItem Style="{StaticResource ImageBarItem}" />
```

Comment: where do we add that <style> tag? sry I am a bit new to this

Comment: Wait a moment, I will share sample for you

Comment: ok thx please do!

Comment: Please refer to code [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/GroupListViewTest/blob/master/GroupListViewTest/ImageMenuBarItem.cs#L16).

Comment: I'll check the code!